# Listview that intents to another listview activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

How do I create another listview through intent from a listview?

Comment: When you say your application crash you should post your logcat. When you want to pass data to intent use `putExtera` instead of `putData`. Post also string arrays XML file.

Comment: mGutenbergAuthors - Pretty, pretty sure this is null

Comment: Yeah, it is and that's what is breaking it. I just cant figure out how to populate it with all the titles and create a listview with an intent.